Running a next.js app on a folder directory
I want to deploy a next.js app to a named folder instead of the root folder, as in
https://example.com/app

There seems to be a problem with routing when I place the app there, so I am looking into this config
next.config.mjs
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  basePath: '/app',
}

export default nextConfig

It works when in dev using http://localhost:3000/app but the images are not found, do I really have to now always add  app. Is there a better way?
<Image
  src='app/next.svg'
  alt="Vercel Logo"
  className="dark:invert"
  width={100}
  height={24}
  priority
/>

